# docker: Error response from daemon... What's the matter?

Tags: java, windows, docker, ubuntu, cmd

I run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker run -i -t ubunru /bin/bash
```

After that I had the following problem:

```
Unable to find image 'ubunru:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository ubunru not found: does not exist or no pull access.
```

Studied various guides, but I can not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Did you intend 'ubuntu:latest' as opposed to 'ubunru:latest' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correctly written word "**ubuntu**".

right cmd:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```